# Why does compiling a C program produce such a long binary?

Tags: c, compilation

I have heard that when a compiler compiles code, what it does is create a file that contains instructions that a machine can execute.  According to [this video,](https://youtube.com/watch?v=QXjU9qTsYCc) a simple program like `int main(){ int i; i = 3; }` should, when compiled, produce a file that's only several bytes long.  So why does clang compile this into a file that's several kilobytes long?

Comment: Read about binary formats like [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). You can also peek into the binary with tools like `objdump` to see the real contents.

Comment: There are certain things the C standard requires an implementation to set up before calling `main()`, such as standard input and output steams (`stdin`, `stdout`, etc), packing command line arguments into a form so `main()` can be called, etc.    Those things involve extra actions - i.e. instructions to execute, data to access - on top of whatever `main()` does.   And most implementations (compilers/linkers, etc) default to embedding code for all that in the executable without checking if it is actually needed.

Comment: Looking at http://timelessname.com/elfbin/ might be interesting. It shows an attempt to build a smaller x86 ELF HelloWorld program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [size of executable files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535188/size-of-executable-files)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is likely due to some `#include` statements that statically bind libraries with your executable, or a compiler and a linker including debugging information.</strike> Of course an executable also contains a lot of OS specific data/information which add up to the size, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048052/what-does-executable-file-actually-contain) for more detailed answers. If you're after a small size executable there's plenty of suggestions in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200292/process-for-reducing-the-size-of-an-executable).

EDIT: Reading more about it, the size comes down to C being a high-level language in the sense that it does not communicate directly with hardware, but rather talks with an operation system. Basically, `main` is [not the entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548601/12062404) of your program and there's a lot that goes on before it is even called. I strongly recommend you reading through [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/hello-from-a-libc-free-world-part-1-v2) and its [follow-up](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/hello-from-a-libc-free-world-part-2-v2) and foremost watching [Matt Godbolt's insightful talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOfucXtyEsU) on the topic. These are all concerned mostly with `gcc` and GNU/Linux, but I think it's fair to assume that similar reasons apply to executable sizes on other operating systems as well.